# How to do extended logging to database with CakePHP?

Tags: database, cakephp, logging

Need to log into a database table (`logs`) all major actions which took place in my app. The actions, for example, would be `login/logout, view, add, update,` etc. So, every time somebody logs in or, say, views a particular record - that would be logged in the database table.

I would like to call that method from all controllers in as simple way as possible - something like `logIt($action, $object, $note)` - as this would be dotted around the place, in every controller. It should also be reasonably efficient.

Do you have any suggestions? What would be the best way to do something like that?

Thanks guys. Regards from a CakePHP newbie.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$this->log($data,'log_file');` anywhere in cake (model, view, controller). The data will be logged to tmp/logs/log_file.log

If it needs to go into DB, you'll need to setup a log method in app_controller, load the model yourself. And call that log in any controller you need.

Comment: It does need to go into the DB. Although your tips there were a bit more general (e.g. lacking code) than I hoped for :-), I did follow them and managed to sort something out. I added a log method in app_controller and calling it from other controllers was pretty straight-forward. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think Anh Phams answer is a lot more "cake" and scalable, but if you need that list to be updated in real time then you'll have to put it into the DB I guess.

The best way to do this otherwise would be a [custom component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/996/Creating-Components) of some sort, which you could attach to your controllers as you see fit. Of course you could always create a simple method in your AppController, which loads a 'log' model and saves a record when you call it.